# Xamarin iOS project with reference to binding launches on sim but not on device

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, ios-simulator, quickblox

I am creating the monotouch bindings to the Quickblox chat service.  I successfully did this on a previous version (1.9.x) but on the 2.0.2 library, having problems getting the new binding to launch on the device.  It launches on the simulator fine.  Guessing it is a problem with linker flags, but have run out of ideas.

The binding project compiles fine.  The DLL is created and I can reference it in my host project.  Running the host project in the simulator works fine.  On an actual device, the app launches but the process crashes before getting past the black screen.  No output in the Xamarin Studio "Application Output" window.  Just nothing.  Any way I can insert some debug info to figure out what is going wrong?

Quickblox provides an iOS sample project with the following settings:

> Other Linker Flags:   -lstdc++  -ObjC -lxml2
>
> Link Binary With Libraries:
>
> libxml2.2.dylib   libresolv.9.dylib  libz.1.2.5.dylib
>   AVFoundation.framework  CoreVideo.framework Quickblox.framework Accelerate.framework CoreMedia.framework AudioToolbox.framework  CoreLocation.framework  CoreDate.framework  CoreGraphics.framework  MobileCoreServices.framework  SystemConfiguration.framework  CFNetwork.framework  UIKit.framework  Foundation.framework

Here is my "linkwith.cs" file in my binding project:

```
using System;
using MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime;

[assembly: LinkWith ("libQuickblox.a", LinkTarget.ArmV7 | LinkTarget.ArmV7s | LinkTarget.Simulator, ForceLoad = true, Frameworks = "CFNetwork SystemConfiguration MobileCoreServices CoreGraphics CoreLocation CoreData AudioToolbox CoreMedia Accelerate CoreVideo AVFoundation Security", LinkerFlags = "-lxml2 -lz -lresolv -ObjC -lstdc++")]
```

I have tried this on two iPhone 5 devices, both running iOS 7.1

If I comment out this particular class (QBRequest.h) in the binding, the project will launch on the device.  It tells me there is something with binding to that particular class.  That class inherits from NSObject and does not import any other libraries, so there is nothing that raises any obvious concerns.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class QBRequest;
@class QBResponse;
@class QBRequestStatus;

@protocol QBResponseSerialisationProtocol;
@protocol QBRequestSerialisationProtocol;
@class QBHTTPRequestSerialiser;

extern const struct QBRequestMethod {
    __unsafe_unretained NSString *POST;
    __unsafe_unretained NSString *GET;
    __unsafe_unretained NSString *HEAD;
    __unsafe_unretained NSString *PUT;
    __unsafe_unretained NSString *DELETE;
} QBRequestMethod;

typedef void (^QBRequestStatusUpdateBlock)(QBRequest *request, QBRequestStatus *status);
typedef void (^QBRequestCompletionBlock)(QBRequest *request, QBResponse *response, NSDictionary *objects);

typedef void (^QBRequestErrorBlock)(QBResponse *response);


@interface QBRequest : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, getter=isCancelled, readonly) BOOL canceled;

@property (nonatomic, copy) QBRequestCompletionBlock completionBlock;
@property (nonatomic, copy) QBRequestStatusUpdateBlock updateBlock;

@property (nonatomic, strong) QBHTTPRequestSerialiser<QBRequestSerialisationProtocol> *requestSerialisator;

// QBHTTPResponseSerialiser<QBResponseSerialisationProtocol>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *responseSerialisators;

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary *headers;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary *parameters;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSData *body;

@property (nonatomic) NSStringEncoding encoding;

- (instancetype)initWithCompletionBlock:(QBRequestCompletionBlock)completionBlock;
- (instancetype)initWithUpdateBlock:(QBRequestStatusUpdateBlock)updateBlock completionBlock:(QBRequestCompletionBlock)completionBlock;

- (void)cancel;

@end
```

The binding entry in my ApiDefinition.cs file is this:

```
[BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
public partial interface QBRequest {

    [Export ("canceled")]
    bool Canceled { [Bind ("isCancelled")] get; }

    [Export ("completionBlock", ArgumentSemantic.Copy)]
    RequestCompletionDelegate CompletionBlock { get; set; }

    [Export ("updateBlock", ArgumentSemantic.Copy)]
    RequestCompletionDelegate UpdateBlock { get; set; }

    [Export ("headers", ArgumentSemantic.Copy)]
    NSDictionary Headers { get; set; }

    [Export ("parameters", ArgumentSemantic.Copy)]
    NSDictionary Parameters { get; set; }

    [Export ("body", ArgumentSemantic.Copy)]
    NSData Body { get; set; }

    [Export ("encoding")]
    NSStringEncoding Encoding { get; set; }

    [Export ("initWithCompletionBlock:")]
    IntPtr CreateWithCompletionDelegate (RequestCompletionDelegate completionBlock);

    [Export ("initWithUpdateBlock:completionBlock:")]
    IntPtr CreateWithStatusUpdateDelegate (RequestStatusUpdateDelegate updateBlock, RequestCompletionDelegate completionBlock);

    [Export ("cancel")]
    void Cancel ();
}
```

Thanks for your ideas!!

Comment: Check both the device console logs (hints just before the crash) and the crash report itself. If the information in them is not obvious then you might want to include them into your question.

Comment: @poupou Thanks for the advice.  Problem is that there are no crash logs being generated on the device, nor any statements in the console.   App comes to foreground with a black screen, then disappears, no logs.  Guess it is not really crashing, almost like the process itself is just exiting.

Comment: Also, setting a breakpoint in the AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching never gets hit.  Not getting that far before exiting.  Not sure how to get any debug info out of this problem.

Comment: Check **both** the device console logs and the crash report <- you should see something (every app that starts logs something) in the device console logs. Otherwise please file a bug report and attach a test case we can build and duplicate the issue.

Comment: Ahh.. thanks @poupou!!  Device console logs reveals some truth.  The exception is being thrown by the QBRequest static initializer.  It is being called before some config data is set and QBRequest is throwing the exception.  Odd that the static initializer is called in a different order on the device than on the simulator.  Now I have to figure out how to step in front of that static initializer to set the config params.  Your comment got me unstuck.  Thanks!!

Comment: Glad to hear it :-) I'm a bit surprised you did not get a crash report (check the logs it's possible there's not enough space left to save new crash reports).

Comment: @poupou  Exactly.. the crash logs were full.  The device console revealed that too.  How can I accept a comment as an answer?  You were a big help, thanks!

Comment: np :-) I turned the comments into an answer - it will prove more helpful for anyone else (googling something similar) and will allow you to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the device console logs (hints just before the crash) and the crash report itself.

> Problem is that there are no crash logs being generated

You should see something (every app that starts logs something) in the device console logs.

Also check the device logs it's possible there's not enough space left to save new crash reports.

> Device console logs reveals some truth. The exception is being thrown by the QBRequest static initializer.

Exactly.. the crash logs were full. The device console revealed that too.